# Impact of using immutable.js with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, immutability

There is a very powerful library called [immutablejs](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js)

The philosophy comes from functional programming that a data structure is immutable and that every operation on a data structure creates a new one. This makes the program more modular, easy to prove and easier to multiprocess the data.

Currently it is used in reactjs. I like the concept from using the scala language. Would it be a good idea to use it with angularjs or would it make a mess with the watcher of the objects, as they would think that all objects were created from scratch and change the whole dom connected to this model on a certain digest?

Comment: I think it will perform very well, so long as you take care in what binds where. Any change on an immutable object will return a new reference, so all your $watchers will be awesomely fast. You will need to pay attention to where your template binds it, however.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [angular-immutable](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-immutable) module availble for the use which has a directive to optimize the digest cycle of the angular when used with immutableJS. You can learn more about it from the [author's blog post](http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/03/02/immutability-in-angularjs-immutablejs/)

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2 will be able to use immutable objects in order to speed up change detection.

Take a look at: http://victorsavkin.com/post/110170125256/change-detection-in-angular-2